# In Scala.js, how to best create an object conforming to a trait from a JS façade?

Tags: casting, scala.js, type-safety, object-literal

Suppose I have this definition in Scala.js for the return type of a function of some library I'm using:

```
@native
trait Link extends Object {
  val href: String = native
  val title: String = native
}
```

What's the best, typesafe way, in Scala code, to define an object literal conforming to this? I thought the `use(...).as[...]` trick would work:

```
val link = js.use(new {
  val href = "value1"
  val title = "value2"
}).as[Link]
```

But this yields the error:

> AnyRef{val href: String; val title: String} does not export a getter href: String

Why?

I also tried this, and as expected it fails:

```
val link = js.use(js.Dynamic.literal(
  href = cap(2),
  title = cap(3)
)).as[Link]
```

gives

> scala.scalajs.js.Object with scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic does not have a getter href: String

Finally, I also tried this:

```
val link = new Link {
  override val href = "value1"
  override val title = "value2"
}
```

and got

> A Scala.js-defined JS class cannot directly extend a native JS trait

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
val link = js.Dynamic.literal(
  href = "value1",
  title = "value2"
).asInstanceOf[Link]
```

This works, but it's not checked by the compiler if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library should declare `Link` as `@ScalaJSDefined` instead of `@js.native`. That would allow you to do the third variant (the one with `new Link { ... }`. I suggest you file a bug report for that library.

As a workaround, either do what you're doing with the `.asInstanceOf[Link]`, or, if you want the `js.use(x).as[T]` safety, use this:

```scala
@ScalaJSDefined
trait LinkImpl extends js.Object {
  val href: String
  val title: String
}

val link = js.use(new LinkImpl {
  val href = "value1"
  val title = "value2"
}).as[Link]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm the one who wrongly wrote the façade types. So what's the advantage of ever defining `@js.native` traits instead of `@ScalaJSDefined` traits in this case?

Comment: In this case, none. For traits, only define them as `@js.native` if you have no other choice (e.g., because it contains an `apply` method).

Comment: @sjrd `ScalaJSDefined` is now gone I believe and no annotation is needed to be able to instantiate a `trait` correct?

Comment: That is correct. No annotation is the new `@ScalaJSDefined`.